# Как загрузить в структуру только часть изображения?

Tags: opengl, opengles

У меня есть изображение (`png`) со спрайтами, которое я хочу разделить и загрузить в отдельные текстуры. Как это правильно сделать?. К примеру, у меня
есть `png` 600х300, котороя я хочу использовать в качестве двух текстур 300х300. На данный момент я просто загружаю ее полностью

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE7);
glGenTextures(1, &glTexture_);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTexture_);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
             0,
             GL_RGBA,
             pictureSize.width(),
             pictureSize.height(),
             0,
             GL_RGBA,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             fromRGBA32.pixels());

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

а уже в шейдере разделяю, но хочу использовать нововведение `es 3` когда мы можем объединять несколько текстур и потом в шейдере определять какую имеено брать (все же лучше передать одну переменную, нежели 2 двумерные координаты, определяющие нужный нам квдрат).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно было бы копировать участки изображения в отдельные двухмерные массивы и загружать их через `glTexImage2D` как обычно, но это неинтересно и медленно.

Можно сделать так:

```
GLint old_row_length;
glGetIntegerv(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, &old_row_length);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, pictureSize.width());
// Здесь делаем `glTexImage2D(...)` столько раз, сколько нужно.
// Все как обычно, только в качестве размера указываем размер участка изображения,
// а в качестве адреса передаем адрес первого пикселя этого участка.
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, old_row_length);
```

Обычно OpenGL считает, что строки  пикселей в передаваемом массиве упакованы плотно, но с `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, ...)` можно заставить его игнорировать лишние байты между строками.

Comment: А разве указание в качестве второго параметра в glPixelStorei как числа, отличного от 1 2 4 8 - не будет приводить к ошибке? В документации, по крайней мере, сказано, что лишь эти 4 числа являются валидными аргументами для функции.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Да, вы правы. Почитал доки, вроде вместо этого должен подойти `GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH`. Исправил ответ.

Comment: Вот только, насколько я понял, так нельзя загрузить правую часть изображения (если поделить изображение на 2 вертикальной чертой)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch А почему нет? Прибавить к указателю половину ширины, умноженную на размер пикселя в байтах. Или сделать `glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS, ширина/2);`.

Comment: ах да, точно. Я как то не подумал, что начало будет отсчитываться от указателя. Будет компьютер под рукой - проверю